# What age was Obi Wan when he died?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, obi-wan-kenobi

What was the exact age of Obi Wan-Kenobi when he dies in *Episode IV: A New Hope*?

Darth Vader was 45 when he died and he was a little younger then Obi-Wan, so what was Obi-Wan's age at death?

Comment: addressed in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12269/did-obi-wan-age-normally?rq=1

Comment: @AakashM, user25884's answer uses the word assume!

Comment: A little older than 45.

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that Alec Guinness was 63 when he played the role of Obi Wan Kenobi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Obi-wan was born in 57BBY (Before the Battle of Yavin). He died in the same year as the [Battle of Yavin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin) (0BBY), hence he died at the age of 57.

> [image]
> <sub><sup>**[SW Card Trader: Obi-Wan Kenobi - Padawan - Base Series 1](https://starwarscardtrader.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi_-_Padawan_-_Base_Series_1)**</sup></sub>

And

> [image]
> <sub><sup>[Keeper of the Holocron's Blog - Leland Chee](https://web.archive.org/web/20090119212402/https://blogs.starwars.com/holocron/13/comments)</sup></sub>

Comment: Admittedly, depending on when his lifeday was, he might have been either 56 or 58 when he died.