# Why did Yoda say nothing after Padme hugs Anakin after the fight with Dooku?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Yoda seems to be the most sensitive to Anakin's state of mind. He has already sensed the fear in Anakin when Padme fell from the ship during the chase of Count Dooku. Surely, he must have understood what's going on between those two after seeing that embrace. He says nothing then. In the aftermath, when Masters Windu, Kenobi and Yoda are discussing the events, again nothing from Yoda. Kenobi, we can assume, is more forgiving of Anakin. Why doesn't Yoda say anything?

[image]

Comment: Know how to keep his mouth shut, Master Yoda does ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is covered in the film's [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel)). At the moment of the hug, it's simply put down to her being *concerned* about his grievous wound.  Yoda is exhausted (from the fight) as well as deep in contemplation and no-one seems to notice anything unusual about her actions:

> *As Anakin and Obi-Wan walked over to the exhausted Yoda, Padmé rushed
> in, running to Anakin and wrapping the sorely wounded young man in a
> tight, desperate hug.*

---

As to why nothing is mentioned later, the very short answer is that it's on their "*to do*" list, but not immediately problematical. The impression seems to be that he's got a bit of a schoolboy crush on Padmé which is something that will need to be dealt with by... erm... reminding him of his duties as a Jedi.

Never in their wildest dreams do they imagine that she's going to reciprocate his feelings and begin an illicit affair with him, something that would destroy both of their careers

> *After some more quiet contemplation, Mace turned a curious gaze upon Obi-Wan. “Where is your apprentice?”*
>
> *“On his way to Naboo,” Obi-Wan answered. “Escorting Senator Amidala home.”*
>
> *Mace nodded, and Obi-Wan caught a glimmer of concern in his dark
> eyes-concern that Obi-Wan shared about Anakin and Padmé. They let it
> go at that time, though, for there seemed greater problems at hand.
> Again, it was Obi-Wan who broke the silence.*

Comment: "destroy both of their careers" and get her killed and him permanently maimed in the process...

Comment: Any parent of a teenager should be very familiar with that "glimmer of concern in his dark eyes..." line =D

Comment: @CortAmmon - I feel like she kinda [led him on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DFOE0td1Yw)

Answer (score 17):

The embrace is not particularly suggestive of Anakin and Padme's romantic relationship given their history together. They met each other while Anakin was a young boy and Padme was a teenager, and then they spent time together on Naboo while Anakin was assigned to protect Padme. At the time of the embrace, Anakin and Padme (and Obi-Wan) had just escaped execution, and Anakin had been badly injured by the fight with Dooku.

It is entirely reasonable for Yoda to think that this was a platonic embrace between two friends who had spent time together and were relieved that they had just survived a traumatic ordeal.

Yoda evidently did not "understand what's going on" since he was still oblivious of Anakin and Padme's romantic relationship in Episode III; recall that Anakin consulted with Yoda regarding his visions of suffering and death, and Yoda wasn't even sure if Anakin was having visions of his own suffering or of someone he knew.

Comment: Aw, c'mon. Since when does a platonic embrace have the girl standing on her toes?

Comment: @muru When the girl is much shorter than the guy. :) Besides, you expect an alien (Yoda) [who has probably never had a romantic relationship](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110879/31936) to pick up on humans' subtle body language cues?

Comment: @Null - never, you say? Every Jedi has sweethearts in EU, it seems. Girlfriend, Obi-Wan had. Qui-Gon, too.

Comment: @Null no, but I do expect Anakin's emotions to be particularly strong at that moment, and for Yoda to pick up on those.

Comment: @muru When Yoda counseled Anakin to "let go of everything" he was afraid to lose, Anakin had just found out he was going to be a father. If Yoda can't pick up on those emotions, I don't see how an embrace would be enough.

Comment: Hmm. Does the senile green friend only pick up on negative emotions then? Close to the dark side, he wanders.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the excellent points made in Null's answer, it's worthy of noting that Palpatine was in full swing in his plotting ways at this point. Note these two lines:

> Palpatine: Master Yoda. Do you really think it will come to war?
>
> Yoda: The dark side clouds everything. Impossible to see the future is.

It wouldn't be too hard to imagine that Palpatine might have been using his dark ways to cloud the reality of the situation, and purposely shrouded Anakin's relationship with Padme because the emotional attachment was the most important vessel for turning Anakin to the dark side.

Comment: Is this “clouding” ever explained somewhere?

Comment: @Michael In countless books, as well as a few mentions in the prequels. Mace Windu mentions specifically in one scene that if their ability to "see" with the Force is diminished, they should inform the Senate, and Yoda councils caution in that regard, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, but how does this clouding work? Why is the Sith’s ability to “see” not limited by the Jedi’s actions/plotting? Why does it only work one way?

Comment: @Michael because that would be against the Jedi code, to deceive for their own gain.

Comment: But it’s for the greater good (which is the Jedi excuse #1)!

Comment: Not sure whether that's a Jedi's #1 excuse or just Obi Wan's ;)